# Преобразование огромных чисел

Tags: c++

Преобразую значения из string в long long

```
val = atoll(a[i].c_str());
```

Как защититься от Васи Пупкина, который записал число, которое большее максимального (9223372036854775807)?
Нужно приравнивать `val` к 0.

Программа ошибок не выдаёт, однако наличие такой недоработки меня напрягает.

Comment: Подключите `<errno.h>`, обнулите `errno` перед `atoll()` и проверьте `errno == ERANGE` после.

Comment: @avp: Функции группы `ato...` порождают неопределенное поведение при переполнении. Они не выставляют `errno`.

Comment: @AnT, вообще-то я проверял перед тем, как советовать в `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0`. Очевидно она реализована через обычную strtoll, которая и выставляет errno

Comment: @avp Что значит "я проверял"? В С/С++ в рпинципе не всуществует никакого "я проверял", а когда речь идет о неопределенном поведении, то говорить о каком-то "проверянии" вообще смешно. Как там реализована `atol` в вашей реализации никому не интересно. Поведение не определено. А ваше "проверяния" - не более чем попытка разглядывания деталей этого неопределенного поведения. Зачем это делать - не ясно.

Comment: Отдельно стоит заметить, что в GNU-шной реализации стандартной библиотеки `atoi` реализуется через прямой каст результата `strtol` к типу `int` без каких-либо проверок на выход за пределы диапазона. То никакой цели определить поведение `ato...` при переполнении перед собой разработчики библиотеки не ставили. Реализация `ato...` через `strto...` - не более чем разумная экономия кода в рамках свободы, предоставляемой все тем же неопределенным поведением. Не пытайтесь заглядывать внутрь реализаций стандартных функций и придумывать несуществующие гарантии на основе того, что вы там увидели.

Comment: @AnT, вот насчет угадываний не надо. В [man atoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoll) явно указано, что поведение `ato...` соответствует поведению `strtol`. / И gnu/linux (с gcc/g++) достаточно распространенная система, чтобы использовать знания о ее поведении. В частности, если определить `__USE_EXTERN_INLINES`, то в реализации `atoll` явно написано `return strtoll (__nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);`

Comment: @avp: Во-первых, то, что написано в man не имеет никакого веса и никакого значения. Спецификация стандартных функций языка С дается только в стандарте языка. Во-вторых, читайте сами внимательнее вашу же ссылку, где ясно написано, что поведение функций `atol()` and `atoll()` совпадает с поведением `atoi()` (с поправой на соотв. целый тип), и черным по белому сказано что поведение `atoi()` отличается от `strtol` тем, что она *не детектирует ошибок*. Т.е. точно слово в слово именно то, что я говрил выше.

Comment: Ваши же эксперименты - это не более чем "диссертация Василия Ивановича" из известного анекдота, где он сделал вывод о том, что "безногий таракан не слышит". Никаких "знаний о поведении gnu/linux (с gcc/g++)" в ваших исследованих не содержится. Но даже если бы и содержались, все равно ни о каком использовании этих "знаний" в контексте программирования на С не может быть и речи. Да и не нужно это никому. Для решения посавленной задачи есть нормальные, специально для того предназначенные средства.

Comment: @AnT, и все же, согласитесь, что если функция Х возвращает значение функции Y, то *их поведение* одинаковое (независимо от того, что именно кто-то написал в мане или стандартах)

Comment: @avp: Если типы возвращаемых значений совпадают - то одинаковое. Только к чему это тут?

Comment: @AnT, к комментариям о *детектировании ошибок*. Ладно, ерунда это все. Я думал, что Вы скорее будете говорить об альтернативных реализациях libc (в т.ч. и для линукса, например,  [musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdlib/atoll.c)) / Интересная либа, вот в ней как раз никакой детекции ошибок в `ato...`

Comment: @avp: Даже в вашем Ubuntu (или как там его), я уверен, нет детекции ошибок в `atoi`, как я говорил выше.

Comment: @AnT, если интересно, в atoi (в смысле INT range) нет, в atoll (и в atoi тоже) есть `Numerical result out of range` для long long. Определить, что это не число, действуя как в strto..., естественно, нельзя.

Comment: @avp: Я это к тому, что отсутствие проверки диапазона в `atoi` (а ее было бы легко реализовать) свидетельствует о том, что унаследованное от `strto...` поведение является не более чем побочной случайностью, а не преднамеренной попыткой ввести контроль за переполнением в функции группы `ato...`.

Comment: @AnT, с этим согласен. Вообще, надо было мне сразу посоветовать ТС использовать неоднократно проверенную `strtoll`, а не смотреть на реакцию `atoll`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, как вариант - использовать `stoll` и перехватывать исключения...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    long long l;
    try {
        l = stoll(s);
    } catch(out_of_range&)
    {
        l = 0;
    } catch(invalid_argument&)
    {
        l = -1;
    }
    cout << "s = " << s << endl;
    cout << "l = " << l << endl;
}
```

Comment: Или проверять errno с тем же `atoll()` без возни с исключениями

Comment: @avp: Функции группы `ato...` порождают неопределенное поведение при переполнении. Они не выставляют `errno`.

Answer (score 3):

Функции группы `ato..` были [полу-]официально "покинуты" стандартом языка С еще в 1995 году (cм. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf). Они не предоставляют никаких средств для обработки ошибочных ситуаций. В стандартной библиотеке С им на смену пришли функции группы `strto...`, которые предоставляют такие средства.

Эти функции не были официально объявлены obsolescent из-за их широкой распространенности в старом коде. Также они потенциально могу быть реализованы более эффективно, чем функции группы `strto...`. Однако реальные реализации этим обычно не занимаются, а просто делегируют вызовы `ato...` в `strto...` с игнорированием потенциальных ошибок.

Поэтому если вы по какой-то причине настаиваете на использовании С-функций для решения подобных задач, забудьте о существовании функций группы `ato...` - это "мертвые" функции. Пользуйтесь функциями группы `strto...`.

Разумеется, учитывая, что ваш вопрос помечен тегом [C++], вам лучше просто воспользоваться аналогичными средствами стандартной библиотеки С++.

Answer (score 0):

Это наиболее быстрая реализация приведения, из мне известных. Она да, требует некоторую проверку на этапе компиляции, но работает, как часы. В цикл `while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')` надо добавить проверку на длину строки, соответствующую длине максимального числа. Типом возвращаемого значения можно играть. Должно работать в разы быстрее зачтенного варианта.

```
  STATIC_ASSERT(1 == '1' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(2 == '2' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(3 == '3' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(4 == '4' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(5 == '5' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(6 == '6' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(7 == '7' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(8 == '8' - '0');
  STATIC_ASSERT(9 == '9' - '0');
  int to_int(const char *p)
  {
     while (*p == ' ')
        ++p;

     int r = 0;
     bool neg = false;
     if (*p == '-') {
        neg = true;
        ++p;
     }
     while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        r = (r*10) + (*p - '0');
        ++p;
     }
     if (neg) {
        r = -r;
     }
     return r;
  }
```

Comment: Или [так](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdlib/atoi.c)

Comment: И в чем же в данном случае смысл "изобретения велосипеда" по сравнению с имеющимися в наличии стандартными функциями? С точки зрения контроля ошибочных ситуаций, этот вариант так же дыряв, что и `atoi`. И работать "в разы быстрее" стандартной функции, это, разумеется, не будет. Что же касается "проверок на этапе компиляции": они избыточны - все это и так гарантируется спецификацией языка.

Comment: Но самое главное, данный ответ не имеет никакого отношения к теме обсуждения, т.е. к поставленному вопросу.

Comment: @AnT поскольку замеры я делал более полугода назад, я не помню во сколько именно раз это быстрее стандартных реализаций компиляторами, которыми мы пользуемся (под линух, солярис, винду), но быстрее было именно в разы, и когда это было критично, оно помогло (только для double).
На вопрос это отвечает, поскольку при введении счетчика даёт контроль за переполнением на усмотрение пользователя.
Насчет гарантий языка, буду признателен за ссылку на стандарт, гарантирующую, что коды символов `0` и `3` действительно отличаются на 3, я такое не нашел в свое время, а потому перестраховался.

Comment: @Arkady: Это о каком "введении счетчика" идет речь? Как предлагается контролировать переполнение?

Comment: @AnT сейчас я вспомнил, что серьезное ускорение и замеры имели место для double (алгоритм примерно тот же), как avp заметил, для int оно, вероятно, просто то же самое, что и стандарт)
Счетчик длины строки. Если макс/мин число возвращаемого типа записывается 11тью символами, достаточно считать длину строки, чтобы она была не больше 10 символов. Да, мы немного "урежем" максимально возможное число таким образом, но для реальных цифр это допущение может быть рабочим.

Comment: @AnT если же нужна возможность прям именно уметь считывать максимальное число, можно усложнить проверку, например, сравнивая строку со строковым представлением максимального числа, но тогда оно действительно не строит затрачиваемых усилий.

Comment: @Arkady: Контроль переполнения через контроль длины строки - это слишком грубо и несерьезно.

Comment: @AnT это вопрос вкуса. Поделитесь ссылкой на раздел стандарта, гарантирующий избыточность тех статических проверок?

Comment: @Arkady В С это раздел "5.2.1 Character sets", в С++ - "2.3 Character sets". Там говорится "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous." (ссылаясь на последовательность 0123456789)

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string s="922337203685477580712324567878";
size_t index;
long long l=std::stoll(s, &index);
if(index!=s.size())
    throw std::runtime_error("bad number");
```

Comment: Убедитесь, что это не сработает: http://ideone.com/9zb5cL

Comment: Тут будет исключение out_of_range. Проверка индекса нужна чтобы отлавливать ошибку на строках с пробелами "1234 4567".

Comment: А о чем спрашивал ТС? *Как защититься от Васи Пупкина, который записал число, которое большее максимального*...